# Error creando el bean Spring

Tags: java, netbeans, spring

Estoy comenzando con Spring y tengo un error que no me deja avanzar, estoy utilizando la etiqueta component para inyectar una objeto en la clase llamada comercial experimentado, tengo aparte un archivo de configuracion.class pero cuando corro el programa me da un error como si no escaneara el objeto que estoy tratando de inyectar en la clase comercialExperimentado aqui esta la clase main donde hago el llamado:

```
    public class UsoAnnotations2 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            
        //ClassPathXmlApplicationContext contexto = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        //leer el class de configuracion
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext contexto = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(EmpleadosConfig.class);
        
        Empleados juan = contexto.getBean("comercialExperimentado", Empleados.class);
        Empleados maria = contexto.getBean("comercialExperimentado", Empleados.class);
        
        if(juan == maria){
            System.out.println("si");
        }
        else
            System.out.println(juan+"\n"+maria);
    
        contexto.close();
    }

}
```

este es el archivo de configuracion:

```
    package pruebaAnnotations;

    import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan("pruebaAnnotations")
    public class EmpleadosConfig {
    
    
    }
```

El archivo donde estoy creando el objeto de tipo informe que estoy tratando de inyectar es esta:

```
    package pruebaAnnotations;

     import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
     import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
     import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
     import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
     import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
     import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    /**
    *
    * @author Cristian
    */
    // con una aotacion puedo darle un nombre al bean @Component("ComercialExperimentado") o
    //el bean toma el nombre de la clase con la primera letra en minuscula
    @Component
    //@Scope("prototype")
    public class ComercialExperimentado implements Empleados{
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("informeFinancieroTrim2") //bean id si mas de una clase implementa la interfaz
    private CreacionInformeFinanciero nuevoInforme;
    //inyecta la clase que implemente la interfaz creacioninformefinanciero osea informefinanciero
    
    /*//Autowired no es nesesario agregar el bean en el xml  
    public ComercialExperimentado(CreacionInformeFinanciero nuevoInforme) {
        this.nuevoInforme = nuevoInforme;
    }*/
    //ejecutar despues de crear solo con singleton y no deben recibir argumentos
    @PostConstruct
    public void metodoInicial(){
    
        System.out.println("dentro del metodo init aqui irian las tareas a ejecutar antes que el 
    bean este listo");
    }
    //ejecuta despues de usar bean
    @PreDestroy
    public void metodoFinal(){
    
        System.out.println("dentro del metodo destroy aqui irian las tareas a ejecutar despues que 
     el bean haya sido usado");
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getTareas() {
        return "vender, vender y vender mas";
    }

    @Override
    public String getInforme() {
       
          return nuevoInforme.getInformeFinanciero();
     }
```

Con la etiqueta @Qualifier le estoy indicando que objeto quiero inyectar ya que varios implementan la misma interface (ya probe dejando solo una clase pero tambien me da el mismo error) aqui esta la clase informeFinancieroTrim2 que es la que yo creo que no se esta escaneando

```
    @Component
    public class InformeFinancieroTrim2 implements CreacionInformeFinanciero{

    @Override
    public String getInformeFinanciero() {

           return "presentacion informe negativo del trimestre 2";
    }
    
    }
```

y esta es la interface que estan implementando

```
    public interface CreacionInformeFinanciero {
    
    public String getInformeFinanciero();
    }
```

el error que me arroja es el siguiente

```
    run:
Jan 20, 2022 10:44:13 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
ADVERTENCIA: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'comercialExperimentado': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'nuevoInforme'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'pruebaAnnotations.CreacionInformeFinanciero' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=informeFinancieroTrim2)}
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'comercialExperimentado': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'nuevoInforme'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'pruebaAnnotations.CreacionInformeFinanciero' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=informeFinancieroTrim2)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:93)
    at pruebaAnnotations.UsoAnnotations2.main(UsoAnnotations2.java:21)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'pruebaAnnotations.CreacionInformeFinanciero' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=informeFinancieroTrim2)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1790)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1346)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    ... 15 more
C:\Users\mcris\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\mcris\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:94: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Comment: ¿Está la clase `InformeFinancieroTrim2` en el package `pruebaAnnotations`?

Comment: si, esta en el mismo paquete

Comment: Creo que deberías añadir la anotación `@Qualifier("informeFinancieroTrim2")` a la clase `InformeFinancieroTrim2`

Comment: Sigue igual añdiendo @Qualifier("informeFinancieroTrim2") a la clase informeFinancieroTrim2 ´error creating bean with name comercialExperimentado': org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'pruebaAnnotations.CreacionInformeFinanciero' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=informeFinancieroTrim2)}´

Comment: @cris1114 ya intentaste inyectar por constructor?

Comment: @RuslanLopez si ya intente por constructor y por setter, voy a instalar eclipse a ver si es netbeans aunque no creo que sea culpa del IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es netbeans que al parecer no escanea las clases, la solucion es darle click derecho al proyecto > clean and build y listo! ya funciona correctamente

Comment: hola, te sugiero aceptar tu propia respuesta. saludos.